# AngularJS: Right using of Controllers and Factories

Tags: angularjs

I am an AngularJS newborn and when I get new project with Angular there are already code that was written by other developers. When I started to deep slide to the code I saw two ways of View-Controller-Factory "connection" implementation.
The first one was as in Angular tutorials:

Controller:

```
 app.controller('dashboardController', function (dashboardFactory){
    /*Controller as implementation*/
    this.widgets = dashboardFactory.getWidgets();
})
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('dashboardFactory', function (){
var widgets = []; 
    return {       
        getWidgets: function () {
            return widgets;
        },
}
```

In the second all controllers function were as pointers to the factory and controller itself has factory variable pointer:

Controller:

```
app.controller('mapController', function (mapFactory){
 this.mapFactory= mapFactory;
this.getRowStatus = mapFactory.getRowStatus;
this.getRowTooltip = mapFactory.getRawTooltip;
})
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('mapFactory', function (){ 
        getRowStatus: function (grid, row) {
            var result = '';
            var currentStatus = row.entity.ONLINE_STATUS;
            switch (currentStatus) {
                case 1:
                    result = 'carInMotionLight';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = 'carInIdleLight';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = 'carAlertLight';
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        },

        getRawTooltip: function (grid, row) {
            var result = 'Engine off';
            var currentStatus = row.entity.ONLINE_STATUS;
            switch (currentStatus) {
                case 1:
                    result = 'In motion';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = 'In idle';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = 'Alert';
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        },
});
```

In second implementation the controller looks cleaner and  inside factory functions, you are in controller scope and if you need to call another factory function you have to use defined factory variable.

I did not found any positive or negative feedbacks of using first or second implementation both are working and both providing same result. 
So what do you think about?Which one is better to use?

Comment: Maybe not a direct answer to your question, but I like to share the John Papa AngularJS styleguide among people starting with AngularJS. If you find time, it has nice - clear content discussing best aprroaches. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 1):

In our commercial work with AngularJS we try to keep controllers 'thin' and push a lot of the logic into the services/factories. We use ES6 with AngularJS 1.5, and sometimes it's a struggle to keep it that way, but in general we try to write a lot of functional programming in the services so the methods are DRY.

Controllers cannot be so DRY because they are tied to particular pages (I suppose this is an argument for utilising a lot of that logic in services).

Comment: So you say the second method is preferable?

Comment: I would say yes, personally. The majority of my co-workers agree with this kind of approach (team of 60+).